# How to GroupBy or Gather on a nested association

Tags: associations, gathering

I've been trying to figure out how to gather or group on a list of a nested associated--and flailing.

Here is a reduced example. I'm interested in performance as the is for a larger example and the operation will be repeated frequently.

Consider:

```
test = {
   <|"me" -> <|"a" -> 1, "id" -> 2|>, 
   "friends" -> {<|"gender" -> 1, "id" -> 5|>} |>,
   <|"me" -> <|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>, 
   "friends" -> {<|"gender" -> 1, "id" -> 5|>, <|"gender" -> 2, 
      "id" -> 12|>, <|"gender" -> 3, "id" -> 13|>} |>,
  <|"me" -> <|"a" -> 3, "id" -> 8|>, 
   "friends" -> {<|"gender" -> 3, "id" -> 13|>} |>
  }
```

I want to collect all "me" associations that have the same "friends" "id" together.  For example, for the above:

```
{
 <|"gender" -> 1, 
   "id" -> 5|> -> {<|"a" -> 1, "id" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>},
 <|"gender" -> 2, "id" -> 12|> -> { <|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>},
 <|"gender" -> 3, 
   "id" -> 13|> -> {<|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>, , <|"a" -> 3, 
    "id" -> 8|>}
 }
```

I've tried many things such as
Gather[test, #1[["friends", "id"]] == #2[["friends", "id"]] &]

and some attempts a Sow/Reap.

Can anyone see how to achieve this?

Comment: `Normal@Merge[Table[friend -> #me, {friend, #friends}] & /@ test, Identity]`

Comment: Palm slap to forehead. How did I miss the existence of Merge? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Normal@
  Merge[
    Map[
      Thread/*MapApply[Rule], 
      Lookup[test, {"friends", "me"}]], 
    Identity]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Merge[Identity] @ Map[Thread[#friends -> #me] &] @ test
```

> ```
> <|<|"gender" -> 1, "id" -> 5|> -> 
>         {<|"a" -> 1, "id" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>},
>   <|"gender" -> 2, "id" -> 12|> -> 
>         {<|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>},
>   <|"gender" -> 3, "id" -> 13|> -> 
>        {<|"a" -> 2, "id" -> 6|>, <|"a" -> 3, "id" -> 8|>}|>
> ```

You can also do

```
Merge[Identity] @
 KeyValueMap[AssociationThread] @
   GroupBy[test, Key @ "friends" -> Key @ "me", First]
```

> same result

and a variation on lericr's method

```
Merge[Identity] @ 
  MapApply[AssociationThread] @ 
    Lookup[{"friends", "me"}] @ test
```

> same result

Comment: `Merge[Identity]@
 MapApply[AssociationThread]@Lookup[{"friends", "me"}]@test` appears to be the  fastest for a larger example of test.